# Cleaner way for coding a repetitive application of a function

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have this function definition which takes an r and applies the function `f` `n` times:

```
r => (1 to n).foldLeft(r)((rx, _) => f(rx))
```

So for `n=3` this is equivalent to `f(f(f(r)))`

I don't like this solution, because it defines a `Range` from `1 to n` which really isn't get used at all, which becomes obvious in the unused parameter `_` in the fold left. This in turn forces me to give a separate name to `rx` which feels wrong to me.

Any idea how I can streamLine this code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's wrong with straight recursion?

```
def ntimes[A](n:Int, f:A=>A, a:A):A = if (n==0) a else ntimes(n-1, f, f(a))
```

Another clean option is

```
Iterator.iterate(a)(f).drop(n).next
```

Answer (score 4):

What about lazy evaluation, using Streams?

```
def applyFunc[A]( f : A => A, a :A  ) : Stream[A] = f( a ) #:: applyFunc( f, f(a) )
```

Then for example you could use it like so:

```
def addOne( i :Int ) = i + 1

val succs = applyFunc( addOne, 0 )

val firstThreeResults= succs.take( 3 ).toList

val onlyFifthResult = succs( 4 )
```

Of course, if f is a heavy computation, you could also calculate the result as an intermediate step:

```
  def applyFunc[A]( f : A => A, a :A  ) : Stream[A] = {

    val res = f( a )

    res #:: applyFunc( f, res )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one alternative, which at least spares the number Range:

```
r => Array.fill(n)(f(_)).reduce((f1, f2) => x => f1(f2(x)))(r)
```

But I find the reduce part rather verbose and hard to read.